# Cognito User Pools authentication and authorization with API gateway

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am trying find way for authentication and authorization based on roles for users. Its a pretty simple use case but i am not able to find simple documentation.

I have rest api(java spring mvc,with dynamodb) working and have API gateway from which i can invoke backend api.

i have used API gateway's congnito user pool.So i can not attach user pool with a api method

Questions.
1) how assign roles to users in congnito user pool
2) Is there simple way to authorize users with certain roles to invoke api defined in aws api gateway? or i have to write custom code/lambda?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, cognito user pool is a mainly a authentication solution and if you plan to authorize users, the new cognito user pool's [users & group](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cognito-groups-and-fine-grained-role-based-access-control-2/) feature will help. This is mainly usable for single tenant applications where a particular user can be in one tenant and the user belongs to a single group.

From the API Gateway side, you can use IAM authentication since you can attach different roles with policies to each group where in the policy, you can grant access to different resource endpoints from API Gateway.